# Changing OS X account login image

Tags: macos, login, accounts

I tried to change the my login account picture.  But the options that are there are only default, recent and camera and no option for edit.

I am left with no options to select picture from any files other than take a picture of myself with the camera or use the default pictures or use the recent picture used from the default.

Anyone got any idea?  It sucks.

Comment: We can't see the screen shot… it's still on your computer. Post it to imgur or flickr etc & paste the link here. Someone with the necessary rep can  inline it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If the options of Defaults, Recents, Photo Stream, Faces, Camera & Linked are simply not sufficient, there's always the option of simply dragging any new picture straight on top of your existing picture, or into Recents…

[image]